# Invisible mouse cursor

Tags: mouse, cursor

There have been some similar posts but nothing specific to me.

Sometimes I boot my laptop and all is well. Other times I boot up and after the login screen my mouse cursor disappears, I can still use it, its just invisible. I start up fire fox and the cursor is visible but only on the application window....

My sysetem is:
samsung R60 Plus, with 4gb ram and a T7500, using the ati Xpress 1250 graphics.

This is with Ubuntu 11.10.

Does any one know of a work around?

Comment: Sorry, I should have also mentioned that this is with 64bit, i didn't have this issue with 11.04.... any advice would be great as im not sure where to start looking.

Comment: Thanks for getting the red pen out Jorge. Nice that you took the time to edit my post rather than answer it. Out of curiosity, what is wrong with ending the post with, "Many thanks, Rob"...?

Comment: your messages are autosigned with your poster name, we tend to edit out the irrelevant information such as "Thanks, [namehere]".

Answer (score 3):

For any one with this problem, an update using the ubuntu update package fixed the problem. I couldn't see anything specific to a fix in the update info but its done the trick!